# How to disable "Modify Style" confirmation dialog in Word 365

Tags: microsoft-word, office365, text-editors, styles, microsoft-word-365

**tl;dr** *How can I turn off "Modify Style" dialog box in Word 365? How can I make Word always re-apply clicked style to the text. Without making any weird questions or confirmations in between?*

---

I don't know what did I enabled or what Microsoft was kind to enable for me, but after 20+ years of using Word, after I go through following scenario:

1. Click any style in Quick Styles list to apply some styling to any part of the text
2. Manually change the style (i.e. change font size etc.)
3. Select any text that has modified style
4. Click the same style again to re-apply the default style

I always see this dialog box:

[image]

How can I turn it off? How can I get the old behavior of Word where clicking any style in Quick Styles list while having text selected was always re-applying clicked style. Without making any weird questions?

<sub>Users in circa 95% of cases clicks any style to re-apply it. Only circa 5% of scenarios you are clicking this button to have underlying style updated automatically. I find making default option to update style a total misunderstanding.</sub>

Comment: I'm not familiar with Word but I believe checking the `Automatically update the style from now on` should default to the radio option selected and not show the dialog afterwards?

Comment: I **am** familiar with Word. You virtually NEVER want to have Automatically update style checked in your style definitions. (Exception is the TOC styles.)

Comment: @CharlesKenyon Exactly, 100% agree. That's why I am so surprised by this dialog appearing and that it does not have "Never automatically update styles" option.

Comment: @oxou A style is a style. Carefully crafted. Used sometimes in dozens of places. You don't want any auto-thing to mess up with this. I am using Word with styles for 20+ years. I still have some styles crated 10+ years ago. But you don't have to be familiar with Word. Think about anything you use. Think about CSS styles in websites that changes automatically (even though used in hundreds of places) with each use of it. Think about AutoCAD where you have carefully defined each default dimension in inches and it asks you over and over again, if you want to automatically update it to millimeters..

Comment: Just a note that this dialog is not exactly new. I do not remember when I first saw it but I expect it if I reapply the current style to text that has direct formatting different from the style. This is my chapter on styles. https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/styles.htm